# Openni registration problem

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm having a problem with the openni registration on a kinect.
As many people around here when i enable the depth_registration option i only receive NaN's.
This is on a fresh install of booth ubuntu 12.04 and ros groovy from yesterday.
I allready tried to follow this "tutorial" [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/53706/registered-depth-image-is-black/#53832) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/54951/kinect-depth-registration-not-working-on-fuerte-and-groovy/) because it's the same problem, but i still can't get the thing to work, and running the OpenNi samples every thing is great.

This is a problem that exists for a long time and no solution yet...
It's very annoying because i need it for my thesis

What can i try to solve this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59469/openni-registration-problem/) by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-03-28**:
I am having the same problem on my laptop: HP Mini 210 w/ Intel Atom, Ubuntu Precise-Fuerte.  Depth registration set to true in openni.launch causes all NAN values.  I am betting this is system dependent because my other laptop with an AMD processor and graphics card works well with openni depth registration (same software).

**Comment by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) on 2013-03-28**:
I also think it is hardware dependent. working on my room there is another studend  with a different pc and everything works fine (just by instaling openni-camera and launch).
For me the strange thing is that the OpenNi binaries works flawless on every pc, but the ROS (and PCL?) library doesn't

**Comment by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) on 2013-04-15**:
If you have this problem please say it on the github page.
here is my issue ticket: https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/issues/13

They didn't seem to find that important (it seams they didn't even read thing right), maybe if more users put the same issue...

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-05-23**:
Hi ! I am struggling with the same problem. Did you find a solution ?

**Comment by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) on 2013-05-23**:
My "solution" was to switch to a 64bits ubuntu.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-05-23**:
Ok. Thank you. My Turtlebot was delivered with a 32 bits computer, so I'll have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in Libopenni-dev. It does not work proper with 32 bit OS. You may work with an older version or install a 64 bit OS.
Regards ,O3

---

Originally posted by [o3p7s5](https://answers.ros.org/users/9096/o3p7s5/) with karma: 86 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1